# JWPlayer in Webview doesn't work Android Studio

Tags: java, android, iframe, webview, jwplayer

I don't know why my iframe doesn't want to work, I use html with external file in asset folder. The iFrame appears, but it's written : **Error loading player: No playable sources found**.

Here is my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webcamView);
WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
}
```

Here is my HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html><head>
    <title>Bundoran Surf Co</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

        <script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
             (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
             m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
             })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

             ga('create', 'UA-40971454-1', 'myipstream.com');
             ga('send', 'pageview');

            </script><script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/bkfmKFnaEeKE5iIACp8kUw.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style><script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/11/jwpsrv.js"></script><script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/11/sharing.js"></script><script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/jwpsrv_frq.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style></head>

<body>
    <div id="banner"></div>

    <div id="my-video"></div>


    <div align="center" id="playerKQLqhEDY5doy_wrapper" style="position: relative; display: block; width: 1000px; height: 600px; overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch"><a id="beforeswfanchor0" href="#playerKQLqhEDY5doy" tabindex="0" title="Flash start" style="border:0;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);display:block;height:1px;margin:-1px;outline:none;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute;width:1px;" data-related-swf="playerKQLqhEDY5doy"></a><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/11/jwplayer.flash.swf" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#000000" id="playerKQLqhEDY5doy" name="playerKQLqhEDY5doy" class="jwswf swfPrev-beforeswfanchor0 swfNext-afterswfanchor0" tabindex="0"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"></object><a id="afterswfanchor0" href="#playerKQLqhEDY5doy" tabindex="0" title="Flash end" style="border:0;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);display:block;height:1px;margin:-1px;outline:none;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute;width:1px;" data-related-swf="playerKQLqhEDY5doy"></a><div id="playerKQLqhEDY5doy_aspect" style="display: none;"></div><div id="playerKQLqhEDY5doy_jwpsrv" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 10;"></div><div id="playerKQLqhEDY5doy_sharing" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 11;"></div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer('playerKQLqhEDY5doy').setup({
                                             playlist: [{
                                                        image: "http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/homepage_offers1.jpg",
                                                        sources: [{
                                                                  file: "http://144.76.75.86/hls/bundoransurfco/playlist.m3u8"
                                                                  }]
                                                        }],
                                             height: 200,
                                             primary: "flash",
                                             width: 315,
                                             controls: true,
                                             autostart: true,
                                             androidhls: true,
                                             sharing: true

                                             });
        </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #playerKQLqhEDY5doy_wrapper {
            left:0em;
            right:0em;
            top:12.2em;
            bottom:-5em;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;

        }
    #photo{
        position:fixed;
        max-width: 100%;
        top:50px;
        left : 0em;
        right:0em;
        display:block;
    }
    iframe, object, embed {

        position:relative;
    }
    </style>
    <span id="photo" align="middle">
            <img src="http://myipstream.com/images/bundoran.jpeg" width="139" height="50" alt="@ Surf Co">



</body></html>
```

Here is my Logcat (updated):

```
04-27 10:42:55.814  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider﹕ Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {528248fc}
04-27 10:42:55.814  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test I/LibraryLoader﹕ Expected native library version number "",actual native library version number ""
04-27 10:42:55.814  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(116)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
04-27 10:42:55.818  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test I/BrowserStartupController﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
04-27 10:42:55.834  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test E/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ BLUETOOTH permission is missing!
04-27 10:42:55.854  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
04-27 10:42:55.858  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8f59b48, tid 11616
04-27 10:42:55.874  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
04-27 10:42:55.874  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
04-27 10:42:55.918  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:mailbox_synchronizer.cc(36)] MailboxSync not supported due to missing EGL image/fence support
04-27 10:42:55.942  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 148K, 6% free 3710K/3928K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
04-27 10:42:55.946  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 6% free 3927K/4152K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
04-27 10:42:55.950  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 6.320MB for 2536932-byte allocation
04-27 10:42:55.954  11616-11626/jardelcompany.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 6405K/6632K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
04-27 10:42:56.010  11616-11640/jardelcompany.test W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(890)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
04-27 10:42:56.294  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
04-27 10:42:56.298  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-27 10:42:56.298  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-27 10:42:56.314  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
04-27 10:42:56.322  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-27 10:42:56.322  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-27 10:42:56.334  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
04-27 10:42:56.538  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test W/AwContents﹕ nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
04-27 10:42:56.830  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'setSampleFrequency'", source: http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/jwpsrv_frq.js (1)
04-27 10:42:56.954  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
04-27 10:42:56.978  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(1082)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:28450CB9]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GetIntegerv: <- error from previous GL command
04-27 10:42:56.998  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
04-27 10:42:57.018  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(1082)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:C0A812B9]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GetIntegerv: <- error from previous GL command
04-27 10:42:57.102  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 89K, 3% free 7193K/7376K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
04-27 10:43:00.362  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test I/chromium﹕ [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
04-27 10:43:00.750  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(1082)] [GroupMarkerNotSet(crbug.com/242999)!:10D3F9B8]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : GetIntegerv: <- error from previous GL command
04-27 10:43:01.518  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(69)] [.Video-Offscreen-main-thread-0xb91cb650]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : glBindTexture: target was GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES
04-27 10:43:01.518  11616-11616/jardelcompany.test E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder_autogen.h(3123)] [.Video-Offscreen-main-thread-0xb91cb650]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_ENUM : glProduceTextureCHROMIUM: target was GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use RTMP sources. RTMP requires Flash, which Android definitely doesn't support, especially in an App.

So, remove the RTMP source, and just use the HLS one.

Then, under this line:

```
autostart: true,
```

Add:

```
androidhls: true,
```

I am not sure if that will work in the app though - you may have to use an HTTP delivered MP4 source.

Comment: thanks for your reply, my new error is : [INFO:CONSOLE(26)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/myHTML7.html

Comment: please check my update, I've updated Logcat, and screenshot (the stream doesn't begin)...

Comment: I updated my code, html, logcat, and added screenshot ;)

Comment: I see. Since this is in a Web View, I cannot guarantee that an m3u8 will play inside of an Web View like this. I would recommend using .mp4 instead.

Comment: Or, you can use our Android SDK to build the player into a native App.

Comment: How can I build the player into a native App ? Have you got some tutorials, advices ? :) Thanks man for your help !